# question about a continuous function and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x,t)$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]\times[\alpha,\beta]$.$t_0 \in [\alpha,\beta]$.Is $\lim_{t\to t_0}f(x,t)=\varphi(x)$ convergence uniformly  about x.Is it true that  $\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta$ if $|t-t_0|<\delta$ we have $|f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)|<\varepsilon ,\forall x$

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your question. Can you reword the sentence "Is $\lim_{t \to t_0}f(x,t)=\phi(x)$ convergence uniformly about x"?

Comment: @DAS I want to know whether it is true that if $|t-t_0|<\delta$ then $\forall x, |f(x,t)-f(x,t_0)|<\varepsilon$ and the $\delta$ only depends on $\varepsilon$ ,doesn't depends on $x$

Answer (score 1):

Yes certainly . You know given $ \epsilon >0$ there is a $ \delta > 0 $ so that if $\  |s-s_0|<\delta$ and $ |t-t_0|<\delta $ then $ |f(s,t)-f(s_0,t_0)|< \epsilon $.
Now just take x=s=$s_0$ ( since |x-x|=0 <$\delta$ ) to get |f(x,t)-f(x,$t_0$)| < $\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since $f$ is continuous you know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $(s,t) \in [a,b] \times [\alpha, \beta]$
$$\sqrt{(s-x)^2 + (t-t_0)^2} < \delta \implies |f(s,t)-f(x,t_0)| < \epsilon$$
So fix $s$ at $x$ and your result follows.

Answer (score 0):

You may be a little confused about the difference between *pointswise convergence* ($\delta$ depends on both x and $\epsilon$) and *uniform convergence* ($\delta$ must hold for all x, so is only in function of $\epsilon$).